# Declaring and Creating VBA custom class with Dim and New

Tags: excel, vba, class

It all started when I was trying to create a new VBA custom class following this [VBA Class Modules – The Ultimate Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/).

So, I tried this:

On `MyCustomClass` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private vMyVar          As String

Public Property Get myVar() As String
    myVar = vMyVar
End Property
Public Property Let myVar(ByVal value As String)
    vMyVar = value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    vMyVar = "test"
End Sub
```

and on my normal module:

```
Option Explicit

Function MyCustomClassTest()
    Dim myVar           As New MyCustomClass
    
    Stop
End Function
```

On the guide, it seems like you can instantiate the custom class right on the `Dim` declaration just like I did on my example, but when I do it and evaluate the variable on the `Stop`, it's set to `Nothing`.

I know I can do:

```
Option Explicit

Function MyCustomClassTest()
    Dim myVar           As MyCustomClass
    Set myVar = New MyCustomClass
    
    Stop
End Function
```

But it's a pain doing it everytime I need a new instance.

There is any way to modify the MyCustomClass module so I can achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Some pretty thorough discussion of this at the linked duplicate.